# Customizing a p:growl message

Tags: primefaces

```
<h:form id="aform">

        <p:growl id="debug-growl" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" sticky="false" />

        <p:inputText id="expression" value="#{debug.expression}" 
            required ="true" requiredMessage="Value is required" />
...
```

If user did not provide an input and submit the form then a pop-up appears and it contains two lines of info.

> **Value is required**
>
> Value is required

I would like to change the subject of the pop-up (a bold part of it) to `Error` for instance.
How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

The bold part of your growl message is the summary message, like a heading. The other one is the detail message. You can disable the one or the other. You've set both on `true`.

You can define and personalize your message by `FacesContext` as follows:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Validation error",  "Value is required");
```

Source: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/growl.xhtml

I hope this helps!